# avoid having to do adb tcpip 5555 every time

Tags: android, debugging, networking, tcp, adb

I like being able to work with my android phone using ADB over WIFI.
After connecting it via USB, I run `adb tcpip 5555`, and then I can disconnect the USB and run `adb connect {phone's IP}:5555`.

What I don't like is that every time I have to restart my phone, I have to reconnect the USB and rerun adb tcpip 5555 command.

Is there any way to make it remember the 5555 setting so it's always in "TCP mode port 5555"?

Thanks

EDIT: my phone is Android 9 limited. Is not rooted. Tried ADB over WIFI and it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest developer preview of Android 11, Android supports *pairing* your device to Android Studio via the new Wireless Debugging feature.

See https://developer.android.com/preview/features#wireless-adb

For older devices, you can use an Android Studio plugin "Wifi ADB" as a temporary workaround. It imitates this feature and works fairly very well.

Comment: I have unrooted Android 9. Installed Wifi ADB and after phone restart it told me it only works with a rooted device. So, uninstalled. I also had a temporary scare because it reported error: more than one device/emulator when I tried to reconnect using adb tcpip 5555. Luckily after turning Developer Options/USB Debugging off and on, it allowed to reconnect.

Comment: That Android 11 feature is wireless debugging right? That gets disabled whenever your wifi is turned off, so you'd have to turn it on again manually every time.